# Unable to correctly combine multiple criteria in query function in Google Sheets

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to combine DATE parameter and SUM & COUNT parameter in Query function in Google sheets.
However, to no avail.

I was able to make them work individually, but not able to find any way to make them work together.

Posting code.

`"SELECT Col2, Col3, count(Col5), sum(Col7), Sum(Col8) where Col2 is not null group by Col2, Col3"`

This is for count and sum

`SELECT Col3 WHERE Col1 > DATE '2021-07-01' AND Col < DATE '2021-07-02'`

This is for date filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try

```
"SELECT Col2, Col3, count(Col5), sum(Col7), Sum(Col8) where Col2 is not null and Col1 = DATE '2021-07-01' group by Col2, Col3"
```

If that doesn't work, please share a copy of your spreadsheet (sensitive data erased). That will make it a lot easier to help you out.

Comment: Buddy this worked perfectly! I was stuck on this since 1 whole day and you solved it in 2secs!
Can you let me know how you figured it out and how I can learn how to combine multiple parameters?